# How to use for loops on multiple variables in python

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I am wanting to use a loop for each of two separate values indicating x and y positions in a 3D matrix. I want to run through all (x, y) combinations for each z value and find the minimum value of each (x, y).  For example, if I have the 2x2x2 matrix A:

```
A = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
     [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

I want to compare (1 and 2), (3 and 4), (5 and 6), (7 and 8). And keep the smallest value of each pair.

I would like to do this using for loops since I will be working with matrices of various dimensions. I know the minimize function I need to use within the loop(s) is min_xy = numpy.min(A[x][y]), but I am unsure of how to write the loops.

Comment: The brackets are not balanced in your example so it's not really clear what you are starting with.

Comment: Does this answer your question: `point=[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]                                                 
[min(i) for j in point for i in j]`

Comment: Please format as per guidelines, since it helps with readability A LOT. And please use correct code examples (your current example is an invalid array, you have either missed an opening bracket or have too many ending brackets).

Comment: Sorry Mark, I just fixed the bracket placement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont even need numpy.

```
A = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]

last = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        min_value = min(A[i][j])
        last.append(min_value)
print(last)
```